# Convert raw ASCII data to Hex string

Tags: c, hex

I have the following code to convert raw ASCII data to Hex string. The full c code can be found [here](https://www.includehelp.com/c/convert-ascii-string-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c.aspx)

```
void str2hex(char* inputStr, char* outputStr)
{
   int i;     
   int counter;
    
    i=0;
    counter=0;
    
    while(inputStr[counter] != '\0')
    {
        sprintf((char*)(outputStr+i),"%02X", inputStr[counter]);
        i+=2; counter+=1;
    }
    
    outputStr[i++] = '\0';
}
```

It works fine for most of the values. But when I am trying the following input from terminal using echo as stdin `echo 11223344556677881122334455667788|xxd -r -p| ./CProgram --stdin`

> 11223344556677881122334455667788

It returns the following output

> 11223344556677FF11223344556677FF

As it can be seen instead of `88` it returns `FF`.

How can I adjust this code to get `88` instead of `FF`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, it is not clear why you are saying that an input of `"11223344556677881122334455667788"` should give exactly the same string back. Is that what you are saying? If not, please clarify.

Comment: `But when I am trying the following input` "How" are you trying the following input? Please post the code, with your modifications, into the question as text. `outputStr[i++] = '\0';` is not needed - `sprintf` already does that.

Comment: I updated the question with the way I try to pass the input to the program

Comment: After seeing how you do the input, I've updated my answer. The problem is, essentially, a problem with sign (`inputStr[counter]` could be a *negative* number).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues all coalescing into your problem.

The first issue is that it's compiler-defined if `char` is a signed or unsigned integer type. Your compiler seem to have signed `char` types.

The second issue is that on most systems today, signed integers are represented using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), where the most significant bit indicates the sign.

The third issue is that vararg functions like `printf` will do [default argument promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) of its arguments. That means types smaller than `int` will be [promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`. And that promotion will keep the value of the converted integer, which means negative values will be *sign-extended*. Sign-extension means that the most significant bit will be copied all the way to the "top" when extending the value. That means the signed byte `0xff` will be extended to `0xffffffff` when promoted to an `int`.

Now when your code tries to convert the byte `0x88` it will be treated as the negative number `-120`, not `136` as you might expect.

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Explicitly use `unsigned char` for the input string:

   ```
   void str2hex(const unsigned char* inputStr, char* outputStr);
   ```
2. Use the `hh` prefix in the [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format:

   ```
   sprintf((char*)(outputStr+i),"%02hhX", inputStr[counter]);
   ```

   This tells `sprintf` that the argument is a single byte, and will mask out the upper bits of the (promoted) integer.